# Elasticsearch Multimatch substring not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch

So I have a record with following field :

```
"fullName" : "Virat Kohli"
```

I have written the following multi_match query that should fetch this record :

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "*kohli*",
      "fields": [
        "fullName^1.0",
        "team^1.0"
      ],
      "type": "phrase_prefix",
      "operator": "OR",
      "slop": 0,
      "prefix_length": 0,
      "max_expansions": 50,
      "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
      "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query": true,
      "fuzzy_transpositions": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine.

But when I remove the letter 'k' from query and change it to :

```
"query": "*ohli*"
```

It doesn't fetch any record.

Any reason why this is happening? How can I modify the query to get the record returned with the above modification?

Comment: Could you share the index mapping and a document with this data?

Comment: @MiguelBarrios : 

Mapping : fullName - string | team - string........

Sample Document :

```{
          "id" : 2,
          "fullName" : "Virat Kohli"
          "team" : [
            "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
            "India"
          ]
}```

Comment: It is possible that you have not defined the fields field as nested in the mapping.
When you have documents with array or brackets values, elasticsearch cannot parse the values if you do not set the field as nested. 
You can find more information through this link if this is the problem in your case.

https://mbarriosa339.medium.com/elasticsearch-nested-field-type-the-importance-of-defining-the-mapping-of-the-index-9ac8d01ba7a8

Comment: @MiguelBarrios there's no nesting in the data but

Comment: @ishallwin did you get a chance to look at my answer, please upvote and accept if it was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first let me explain you why your existing query didn't work and then the solution of it.

**Problem** : you are using the `multi_match` query with type `phrase_prefix` and as explained in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html#query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix) it makes a prefix query on the last search term and in your case you have only 1 search term so on that Elasticsearch will perform the phrase query.

And prefix query works on the exact tokens, and you are using standard analyzer mostly, default for `text` fields so for `fullName` field it will have `virat` and `kohli` and your search term also generates `kohli`(notice smallcase `k`) as standard analyzer also lowercase the tokens, above you can check with the `explain` API output in your first request as shown below.

```
"_explanation": {
                    "value": 0.2876821,
                    "description": "max of:",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "value": 0.2876821,
                            "description": "weight(fullName:kohli in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
```

**(note he search term in the weight)**

**Solution**

As you are trying to use the wildcard in your query, best solution is to use the `wildcard` query against your field as shown below to get results in both case.

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "fullName": {
        "value": "*ohli",
        "boost": 1.0,
        "rewrite": "constant_score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And SR

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_shard": "[match_query][0]",
                "_node": "BKVyHFTiSCeq4zzD-ZqMbA",
                "_index": "match_query",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 2,
                    "fullName": "Virat Kohli",
                    "team": [
                        "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
                        "India"
                    ]
                },
                "_explanation": {
                    "value": 1.0,
                    "description": "fullName:*ohli",
                    "details": []
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Understood very well. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem using query_string for now, understanding that the better approach would be to use ngram.

Comment: @ishallwin yes ngram is better approach